# Defining StackPanel resources programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm just poking around some WPF samples I found online, and came across an odd behaviour which I have simplified it below:

```
  <StackPanel Name="sp1">
    <StackPanel.Resources>
      <!--<src:ItemsForSale x:Key="MyData"/>-->
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <ListView Name="itemsControl"  ItemsSource="{StaticResource MyData}">
      <ListView.View>
      </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
  </StackPanel>
```

If I un-comment line 3 (the resource definition) everything works great.
However, if I comment that line out, and programmatically add the following:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    sp1.Resources.Add("MyData", new ItemsForSale());
}
```

I get the runtime exception `A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll`

I've tried adding the resource in the stackpanel's `Loaded` and `Initialized` event to no avail.

Comment: What does the `InnerExeception` say?

Comment: `{"Cannot find resource named 'MyData'. Resource names are case sensitive."}`

Comment: Control which uses that resource cannot be initialized.

Comment: @dkozl Nope - sp1 is a null reference at that point.

Comment: I've just realized that. But point still stands. You need this resource before that control is initialized. It can be some dummy resource which can be replace later

Comment: @maxp: Try put this line `sp1.Resources.Add("MyData", new ItemsForSale());` in [`Window.ContentRendered`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.contentrendered(v=vs.110).aspx) event.

Comment: @AnatoliyNikolaev thanks, unfortunately same `cannot find resource` error as before.

Comment: Does it help to put the call to Add before `InitializeComponent`?

Comment: @PeterRitchie nope, `sp1` is a null reference before then.

Comment: In my point of view it makes no sense what you are trying to do. Why add the resource instead of adding the itemssource directly? Something like: itemsControl.itemsSource=new ItemsForSale();

Comment: @maxp, try keeping that line where it is just change `StaticResource` to `DynamicResource`. It seems to solve the problem in my case

Comment: @dkozl very cool, that works, thanks for perservering. If you post it as an answer I will mark it so.

Comment: @sexta13 you are right, it probably doesnt make sense from a design perspective but im just playing around and testing / learning the boundaries of WPF.  By the way I quickly tested your solution and it does work so thanks for that.

Comment: you're welcome. The dynamicresource is used when you don't know exactly when the resource is initialized but you know that it will be initialized. if you use staticresource, it must be declared in xaml before you used it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To sum up comments problem was caused by control that required `MyData` resource during initialization and threw this exception:

> Cannot find resource named 'MyData'. Resource names are case sensitive

To solve the problem instead of `StaticResource` use `DynamicResource`

Comment: Interesting that the xaml based definition of the resource, and the programmatic both work when the `ItemSource` is set to `DynamicResource`